# In liferay, how can I capture a user's visit to a group?

Tags: liferay

I am building a notification system and need to store the last time a given user visited a private (or separately public) page for a given group.

Is there a way to build a listener that will be triggered every time a new page is loaded ?

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track!

First in your plugin create `/WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml`. Write:

```
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
</hook>
```

Next, create `/WEB-INF/src/portal.properties`. Define `servlet.service.events.pre` with the listener class:

```
servlet.service.events.pre=com.example.hook.events.ServicePreAction
```

Next, create that class:

```
package com.example.hook.events;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServicePreAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ActionException {
    }

}
```

From there you can grab the `ThemeDisplay` object from the request which will contain all the information you need.